# WPF - Dynamic content in dynamics TabControls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, tabcontrol, radgridview

Even the title makes me laugh...

So, my code looks like that so far :

```
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel x:Name="wpVTList" Margin="70,356,1541,150">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding VTList}"
                    TabStripPlacement="Left"
                    Padding="0,10,0,0"
                    x:Name="tcVTList">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               Width="270"
                               FontSize="20"
                               FontFamily="Calibri"
                               Margin="0,5,0,5"
                               Padding="30,0,0,0"
                               Height="27"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseUp="tbkVTList_MouseUp" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Here is my MainWindow, or at least the window which will display everything, where I create as much tabs as I have in an ObservableCollection of string, which is supposed to be filled dynamically by a query or something.

Beside, I've created two customs userControls like that :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Configurateur.Configuration.TableauEcrans"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="175" Width="470">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        ...
    </Grid.Resources>

    <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding CamerasList}"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         ClipToBounds="True"
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                         telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"
                         CanUserFreezeColumns="False">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                        Header="Name"
                                        UniqueName="Name"
                                        Width="*"
                                        HeaderTextAlignment="Center"  />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Price}"
                                        Header="Price"
                                        UniqueName="Price"
                                        Width="65"
                                        HeaderTextAlignment="Center" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Amount}"
                                        Header="Amount"
                                        UniqueName="Amount"
                                        Width="100"
                                        HeaderTextAlignment="Center" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And then, back to my MainWindow I can use them by adding :

```
<Grid x:Name="gridTableaux" Margin="376,356,0,0">
    <custom:UCCameras Margin="10,41,944,453" />
    <custom:UCOwner Margin="10,411,1054,0" />
</Grid>
```

right after my wrapPanel. It works, they're all here. I put them in a grid in order to delimit where is the dynamic area in my MainWindow. Each userControl is a gridView, and a gridView is filled by an ObservableCollection of a class (i.e. Camera.cs) which contains properties like Name, bounded to the columns in my UC.

What I want to do is to display a new userControl in my MainWindow for each tab, with different informations. For example, if a user fills a row in the gridView in the first tab, he has to find an empty gridView if he chooses another tab. And then, if he comes back to the first tab, he is supposed to see what he wrote in the gridView at the beginning.

1) I don't really see how to use my UCs in each tab since they are created dynamically. I don't know where to put them in my code since I want them to be in the grid (the one which delimits the area where everything happens), at the other side of the MainWindow, or kind of.

2) I have absolutly no idea of how to save these entered values between each tab, and how to choose which one I can use (because of the dynamic way).

I suppooosed... that each tab is a list (ObservableCollection works fine for everything I do) of an OC of class. So my class is a camera (= a row of my gridView) with properties (= cells in my row), contained in an ObservableCollection (= what my gridView has), contained in an ObservableCollection> (= my tabs, with the main grid inside).

Any idea ? I hope I did something that makes sense for what I try to do, I'm still new in WPF. Maybe an OC of UC..?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: No idea ? I really need that, I can't go further in my project without it...

Comment: Please some help... Or at least is it even possible ?